# SQL syntax to achieve the "opposite" of LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm very rusty on the little SQL I once learned, and while I totally get `SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 LIKE pattern`, what I need is:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE pattern_instance LIKE column2  -- legal or not?
```

For example, I might have a `product family` table which has information about the `Coca Cola` range, and for which I might store `coca%` in column2 ready to match specific instances of products such as `Coca Cola 500ml can` or `Coca Cola 1.5L bottle`. Given such a specific product instance, how would I find the `product family` in this case?

I need to implement a query to do this in `PostgreSQL` in case their syntax differs from standard SQL.

Edit: The sense in which I mean the "opposite" of `LIKE` is that reference material gave the `WHERE column LIKE pattern` form, but a query in which I used `WHERE instance LIKE column` (and column contained the pattern) failed. Turns out the source of the failure was NOT having the `LIKE` parameters the opposite way around, but something else entirely...

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I kind of understand your question (and it seems interesting). Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: See comment on accepted answer - schoolboy error + rusty brain = worthless question :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the pattern in a column:

```
WHERE 'Coca Cola' LIKE column2
```

would match rows where `column2` contains `'Coca%'`, for instance.

Comment: Ugh. My bad. I tried `SELECT id FROM table WHERE "Coca Cola" LIKE column2` which failed. I thought it was because you could only have `column LIKE pattern` and not `pattern LIKE column`... but my rustiness led me to overlook the fact I was using double quotes around `Coca Cola`. Groan...